# python-pip : ImportError: cannot import name main

Tags: debian, python, pip

I am using Debian 9.5 Stretch release. I am having import error while using pip. When I try using pip it says:

[image]

However I can use python:
[image]

I have two versions of python installed: 2.7 and 3.5

Output of which pip : `/usr/bin/pip`

When I tried reinstalling it using apt-get pip worked completely fine for the first time but the next time it shows the same error

Contents of `/usr/bin/`

[image]
[image]

Don't know whats the problem.

Comment: Add the output of `which pip` to your question. Also, did you install 3.5 via `apt-get` or was it compiled?

Comment: i installed it using apt-get

Comment: output of which pip : /usr/bin/pip

Comment: In `/usr/bin`, are is there more than one `python` and `pip` such as `python` and `python3` and `pip` and `pip3`?

Comment: same error for pip3

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade pip` and `pip3 install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: same error while using `pip install --upgrade pip` or `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85290/discussion-between-siddharth-mishra-and-nasir-riley).

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely happened because you were using two different package managers (`dpkg` or its frontend `apt-get`, and `pip` itself) on the same prefix (`/usr`). I assume that either

- a recent `apt-get upgrade` updating some dependencies, but some other files that were installed by `pip` didn't get updated because `dpkg` and `apt-get` simply didn't know about them OR
- you removed a package with `apt-get remove`, and as `apt-get` wasn't aware of anything using this package (as the other package was installed by `pip` and thus not in the `dpkg` database), it didn't warn you about breaking other packages.

Without knowing which packages were installed with which package manager, I cannot give you any really specific advice how to repair your system, only general advice:

**Don't use multiple different package managers.** Only ever use one package manager for a given (sub-)tree of your filesystem, or you will get inconsistencies and/or conflicts. Debian's package manager for the `/usr` tree is called `dpkg`, and without calling it *noone* should *ever* touch `/usr`.

It certainly doesn't help that most python-related people you'll encounter try to push pip, even going as far as telling you to `sudo pip install`; don't. There are distro packages containing python stuff for a reason. Also see [this related question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice) and [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004708/osx-el-capitan-sudo-pip-install-oserror-errno-1-operation-not-permitted/33004920#33004920).

---

You can try to repair the mess by installing a fresh pip with

```
apt-get purge python-pip python3-pip
apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
```

however there may be files left behind that might interfere, which `dpkg` doesn't know about as they were installed by `pip`. The sure-fire way would be checking all files under `/usr/lib/python*` whether they belong to a debian package, and if not, delete them without exception.

Again, *only* use `dpkg` and its frontend tools like `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `synaptic`, ... to modify `/usr`. If you need to install anything system-wide that's not available as `.deb` package, either create a package and install it with `dpkg`, or install it under `/usr/local`.

Comment: getting errors purging python-pip. Cannot copy the whole log, it's too long

Comment: What's the first actual error message that it displays (with a few lines of pre-context)? Also, try doing `apt-get purge python-pip` and `apt-get purge python3-pip` separately.

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
`

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: this was for python-pip

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: for python3-pip

Answer (score 1):

Set python2.7 as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

select python2.7.

Remove `pip`:

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall pip
sudo apt purge --autoremove python-pip
```

Reinstall it:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Check the `pip --version`:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Do not upgrade `pip` to the latest version.

Comment: can't use any of those commands. each of them shows some type of error

Comment: dpkg shows some error about unable to configure pip :`Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 334637 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-pip (9.0.1-2) ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
`

Comment: removing also shows error : `dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: @SiddharthMishra You get the above error because you have set Python3.5 as default , see my update.

Comment: Each command worked except pip --version, it shows the same import error as mentioned in my question

Comment: @GAD3R there's a typo here.  It should be "sudo apt purge --autoremove python-pip"

Answer (score 0):

Try out this command:

```
hash -d pip
```